# merge two multidimensional arrays by value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to merge two arrays (they come from mysql queries) by a common value but unfortunately without luck until now.

So basically, I have two separate arrays as you can see below, the first one is called $step1 and the second one $step2

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [inventory_id] => 4
        [1] => 13
        [box] => 13
        [2] => 4
        [wine_id] => 
        [3] => 34
        [quantity] => 34
        [4] => xx@googlemail.com
        [email] => xx@googlemail.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [inventory_id] => 9
        [1] => 0
        [box] => 0
        [2] => 17672
        [wine_id] => 
        [3] => 538
        [quantity] => 538
        [4] => xx@googlemail.com
        [email] => xx@googlemail.com
    )
)

Array
( 
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [wine_id] => 4
        [1] => Ajaccio (CORSE)
        [villesetregion] => Ajaccio (CORSE)
        [2] => Ajaccio
        [villes] => Ajaccio
        [3] => (CORSE)
        [regions] => (CORSE)
        [4] => Clos d'Alzeto  2008
        [nometannee] => Clos d'Alzeto  2008
        [5] => Clos d'Alzeto
        [nom] => Clos d'Alzeto
        [6] => 2008
        [annee] => 2008
        [7] => 8 à 11 €
        [prix] => 8 à 11 €
        [8] => Guide 2010
        [anneeduguide] => Guide 2010
        [9] => 2
        [etoile] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17642
        [wine_id] => 17642
        [1] => Pauillac (BORDELAIS)
        [villesetregion] => Pauillac (BORDELAIS)
        [2] => Pauillac
        [villes] => Pauillac
        [3] => (BORDELAIS)
        [regions] => (BORDELAIS)
        [4] => Chateau Latour  2007
        [nometannee] => Chateau Latour  2007
        [5] => Chateau Latour
        [nom] => Chateau Latour
        [6] => 2007
        [annee] => 2007
        [7] => 75 à 100 €
        [prix] => 75 à 100 €
        [8] => Guide 2011
        [anneeduguide] => Guide 2011
        [9] => 2
        [etoile] => 2
    )
)
```

the queries in mysql are the following :

```
$step1 :
$query2 = "SELECT* FROM `inventory_users` WHERE email='".$email_user."'";

$step2 : 
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM `vins_tbl` WHERE wine_id IN (".implode(',', $wine).")";
```

the database structure for *inventory_users* is :

```
1   inventory_id    bigint(20)          
2   box int(11)         
3   wine_id int(11)         
4   quantity    int(11)         
5   email   text    latin1_swedish_ci
```

and for *vins_tb*:

```
1   wine_id int(5)          Oui NULL        
2   villesetregion  varchar(65) utf8_general_ci     
3   villes  varchar(50) utf8_general_ci             
4   regions varchar(30) utf8_general_ci         
5   nometannee  varchar(105)    utf8_general_ci         
6   nom varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     
7   annee   varchar(4)  utf8_general_ci     
8   prix    varchar(13) utf8_general_ci     
9   anneeduguide    varchar(10) utf8_general_ci     
10  etoile  varchar(2)  utf8_general_ci     Oui NULL
```

and I want to merge the two arrays by the wine_id key, how can it be done ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1) these arrays come from a mysql query? 2) in your first array `wine_id` appears null.

Comment: mmm... and also I want a _verre_  of “Chateau Latour”...

Comment: yes they come from a mysql query

Comment: Can you edit question showing your db structure and query? Because yes, it is possible joining arrays, but can be more performing change the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join values directly in mySQL query by this way:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM inventory_users
       LEFT JOIN vins_tbl 
              ON inventory_users.wine.id = vins_tbl.wine_id
           WHERE email='{$email_user}'
";
```

I use `LEFT JOIN`, that will retrieve also `inventory_users` without any `vins_tbl.wine_id`, but - because probably it is not your case - you can replace `LEFT JOIN` with simple `JOIN` (or `INNER JOIN`, they are alias).

Also, I see that your array has either numeric and associative keys: if you use PDO driver, you can perform a `->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )` to have only associative keys.

**Please note:** I don't have tested the query, so — if it doesn't work fine — feel free to comment.

---

- Read more about [mySQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much! Lost so much time trying to solve the problem in PHP and it was so easy in SQL!!

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the comments that you should join them in the query and not in PHP (assuming possible in your case), here is a simple way to join the arrays.

```
$array1 = array(
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'John'
),
array(
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Bob'
)
);
$array2 = array(
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'money' => 3000
),
array(
    'id' => 2,
    'money' => 5000
),
);

foreach($array1 as $part1){
$found = false;
foreach($array2 as $part2){
    if($part1['id'] == $part2['id']){
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if($found){
    $part[] = $part1 + $part2;
}
}
var_dump($part);
```

---

Should you have any questions, even about the SQL join statement (in your Select).

Don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I opted for the SQL join statement.